# How to horizontally align sketches in fusion360?

Tags: cad, fusion360

I'm working in fusion360. I have 5 circle sketches that I need to all line up in a vertical line. I tried setting constraints, but they were just putting the circles in the exact same x y positions. I just need each circle to have to same x coordinate.

[image: The image attatched shows 5 circles, all with different x values]

Comment: What is the relationship with 3D printing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP. Unfortunately, questions about 3D software are off-topic, unless the resulting model is going to be printed - please see the [**CAD** section](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It may seem unfair, but we just can't support purely 3D software questions. However, if you were using Blender, then there is a [Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/), but there is not one, unfortunately, for Fusion. TBH, I'm really not sure where on StackExchange that questions about 3D modelling are on topic.

Comment: If SE is not a requirement, https://www.reddit.com/r/Fusion360 may be of value in this case..

Comment: Or maybe [SE.Graphic Design - 3D](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d). Or [SE.Engineering - CAD](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cad) or [SE.Engineering - Solidworks](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidworks).  See [Where can questions that are purely about 3D modelling, or CAD, software be asked?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/558/4762)